# Parsing Nested XML and flatten the data into rows - PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, xml-parsing, aws-glue

I have a complicated xml file that I need to parse and flatten using PySpark. I will be leveraging AWS Glue and Spark framework to complete this task. I am able to convert my xml file to spark dataframe but I need to flatten the data. Is it possible to separate PRVDR_INFO and ENROLMENT into 2 different dataframes so I can link them together using a surrogate key?? Check output below.

Below you will find my nested XML file. This XML file has 2 top elements which are PRVDR_INFO and ENROLMENT.

```
<PROVIDER>
    <PRVDR_INFO>
        <INDVDL_INFO>
            <BIRTH_DT>19831222</BIRTH_DT>
            <BIRTH_STATE_CD>VA</BIRTH_STATE_CD>
            <BIRTH_STATE_NAME>VIRGINIA</BIRTH_STATE_NAME>
            <BIRTH_CNTRY_CD>US</BIRTH_CNTRY_CD>
            <BIRTH_CNTRY_NAME>UNITED STATES</BIRTH_CNTRY_NAME>
            <BIRTH_FRGN>X</BIRTH_FRGN>
            <NAME_LIST>
                <INDVDL_NAME>
                    <NAME_CD>I</NAME_CD>
                    <NAME_DESC>INDIVIDUAL NAME</NAME_DESC>
                    <FIRST_NAME>LEO</FIRST_NAME>
                    <LAST_NAME>MESSI</LAST_NAME>
                    <TRMNTN_DT>2010-12-27T09:43:18.000000000</TRMNTN_DT>
                    <DATA_STUS_CD>HISTORY</DATA_STUS_CD>
                </INDVDL_NAME>
                <INDVDL_NAME>
                    <NAME_CD>I</NAME_CD>
                    <NAME_DESC>INDIVIDUAL NAME</NAME_DESC>
                    <FIRST_NAME>LEO</FIRST_NAME>
                    <MDL_NAME>A</MDL_NAME>
                    <LAST_NAME>WHITE</LAST_NAME>
                    <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
                </INDVDL_NAME>
            </NAME_LIST>
            <XX_DEA>
                <DEA_NUM>XX0919969</DEA_NUM>
                <EFCTV_DT>20030103</EFCTV_DT>
                <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
            </XX_DEA>
        </INDVDL_INFO>
    </PRVDR_INFO>
    <ENROLMENT>
        <ABC_999>
            <ENRLMT_INFO>
                <ENRLMT_DTLS>
                    <FORM_TYPE_CD>1111</FORM_TYPE_CD>
                    <ENRLMT_ID>I3994444141</ENRLMT_ID>
                    <ENRLMT_STUS_DLTS>
                        <STUS_CD>06</STUS_CD>
                        <STUS_DESC>APPROVED</STUS_DESC>
                        <STUS_DT>2019-09-25T14:11:08.0000000</STUS_DT>
                        <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
                        <ENRLMT_STUS_RSN>
                            <STUS_RSN_CD>048</STUS_RSN_CD>
                            <STUS_XXX_DESC>APPROVED AFTER 2nd CONTACT</STUS_XXX_DESC>
                            <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
                        </ENRLMT_STUS_RSN>
                    </ENRLMT_STUS_DLTS>
                </ENRLMT_DTLS>
            </ENRLMT_INFO>
            <PEC_SGNTR>
                <CRTFCTN_SGNTR_DT>20101109</CRTFCTN_SGNTR_DT>
                <FIRST_NAME>MIKE</FIRST_NAME>
                <LAST_NAME>BLACK</LAST_NAME>
                <TIN>555669999</TIN>
                <TAX_IDENT_TYPE_CD>S</TAX_IDENT_TYPE_CD>
                <SGNTR_EFCTV_DT>20101109</SGNTR_EFCTV_DT>
                <SGNTR_STUS_CD>9</SGNTR_STUS_CD>
                <DATA_STUS_CD>CURRENT</DATA_STUS_CD>
            </PEC_SGNTR>
        </ABC_999>
    </ENROLMENT>
</PROVIDER>
```

The code below give me 2 columns with nested data but I need to flatten this data into multiple rows. But since output ENROLMENT and PRVDR_INFO are top elements, I would like to separate them into 2 different frames with a FK to link them.

Current Output:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|           ENROLMENT|          PRVDR_INFO|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|{{{{I3994444141, ...|{{US, UNITED STAT...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Code below:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

try:
    rowTag = "PROVIDER"

    # Script generated for node S3 bucket
    df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"rowTag": "PROVIDER"},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="xml",
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://aws-glue-bucket/xml_files/small_xml.xml"]
    })
    
    print(" *********** Printing schema *************")
    df.printSchema()
    
    print(" *********** Printing Data *************")
    df.show(5)
    
    df1 = df.toDF();
    df1.show(8);
    
except Exception as glue_exception_error:
    print("##################### -- Error: "  + str(glue_exception_error) + " -- ##########################")
    raise
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your error, you're probably missing a dependency:

```
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: xml. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

Have you added any jar for parsing xml to your `$SPARK_HOME/jars` folder? If not, try out `spark-xml` from [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml). To choose the correct version, click on one of the available version and have a look at which Spark dependencies are shown. Make sure to match your Spark version to the one of the `spark-xml` that you choose.

Once you have chosen a version, download the `.jar` file and move it to `$SPARK_HOME/jars`. Then try running again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i'm using spark 3.3. Which version in Maven do i need? can you please help. Thanks

Comment: Then you can try to grab the latest version: `0.15.0`. Try downloading the jar and put it in the folder like in my answer. Fingers crossed! Don't hesitate to get back if it doesn't work :)

Comment: Hi, I'm not have issues with the dependencies anymore, and would like some guidance on how to flatten the data within my data frame. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: You're very welcome. If you have a new question, don't hesitate to make a new post! Also please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you, this helps in keeping this website of high quality :)